# Shell/terminal/bash command or script for copying list of files from one project to another

Tags: bash, shell-script, shell, terminal

Let's say I have a project called my-project/ that lives in it's own directory and has the following file structure.

my-project/

```
.
├── src
│   ├── index.html
│   ├── main.js
│   ├── normalize.js
│   ├── routes
│   │   ├── index.js
│   │   └── Home
│   │       ├── index.js
│   │       └── assets
│   ├── static
│   ├── store
│   │   ├── createStore.js
│   │   └── reducers.js
│   └── styles
└── project.config.js
```

Now let's say I have a new project called my-new-project that also lives in it's own directory and has the same file structure as my-project but it contains an additional file called my-files-to-copy.txt

my-new-project/

```
.
├── src
│   ├── index.html
│   ├── main.js
│   ├── normalize.js
│   ├── routes
│   │   ├── index.js
│   │   └── Home
│   │       ├── index.js
│   │       └── assets
│   ├── static
│   ├── store
│   │   ├── createStore.js
│   │   └── reducers.js
│   └── styles
├── project.config.js
└── my-files-to-copy.txt # new file added to tree
```

my-new-project/ has the same file structure but different file contents than my-project/

Now let's say my-files-to-copy.txt contains a list of files I want to copy from my-project/ and write to the same path in my-new-project/ to overwrite the existing files in my-new-project/ at those locations.

my-files-to-copy.txt

```
src/main.js
src/routes/index.js
src/store/reducers.js
project.config.js
```

How can I accomplish this with a terminal/bash/shell command or script?

I think I might be able to do:

```
cp my-project/src/main.js my-new-project/src/main.js
cp my-project/src/routes/index.js my-new-project/src/routes/index.js
cp my-project/src/store/reducers.js my-new-project/src/store/reducers.js
cp my-project/project.config.js my-new-project/project.config.js
```

Maybe some type of `rsync` command will do?

But as the number of files scales, this method will become less efficient. I was looking for a more efficient solution that would allow me to leverage the file that contains the list of files (or at least a script) without having to write a separate command for each one.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

This is what `cpio` is for: copying a list of files. I always find the "in" and "out directions confusing and am glad the GNU one has `--create` and `--extract`.

```
 cd your/source/dir
 cpio --create < my-files-to-copy.txt | (cd your/dest/dir && cpio --extract)
```

There are lots of options for `cpio` to govern things like preserving ownership / timestamps. The man page will guide you. One big gotcha to know about is `cpio` will not create directories unless you (a) copy them to the stream (eg in your list of files to copy) or (b) use the `--make-directories` option on the extract side.

Comment: This works great. How do I copy recursively a directory within the list at my-files-to-copy.txt? I made this into a separate question. https://unix.stackexchange.com/q/481070/167174