# How to recursively copy a directory using cpio?

Tags: recursive, cpio

How do I copy recursively a directory within the list at `my-files-to-copy.txt`?

```
cd my/source/dir
cpio --create < my-files-to-copy.txt | (cd my/dest/dir && cpio --extract)
```

my-files-to-copy.txt

```
src/main.js
src/routes/index.js
src/my-app/ # a directory with it's own child tree I want to recursively copy
```

Comment: `cpio` doesn't seem to support recursive copying like you want it to. Would you be able to use any of `pax`, `tar`, `cp`, `rsync` instead?

Comment: `cpio` supports such a copy but with limited meta data support, see man page:http://schillix.sourceforge.net/man/man1/cpio.1.html - check the `pass mode` section. `cpio` however neither has a `--create` nor a `--extract` option. So how did you come to your question?

Comment: @schily They are using GNU `cpio` which does have those options. `--create` is an alias for `-o` and `--extract` is an alias for `-i`.

Comment: The pure existence of those non standard aliases to standard options can be seen that the related GNU tools are trying to create a vendor lock in. So these aliases are not helpful. On the other side, it is easy to write documentation that  marks non-standard features...

Comment: @schily `cpio` is not a standard utility anymore.

Comment: The SUSv2 standard was not withdrawm and the basic method is the same for all GNU programs that are based on the functionality of standard utilities.

Answer (score 1):

I'm afraid `cpio` can't really do this, unless you do some extra scripting to detect the directory pathname and walk through it to extract the pathnames of all files below it, as a way of "pre-processing" your list file.

It would be far easier to use another tool, such as `rsync` (note the extra `-r` after `--files-from`!):

```
rsync -a --files-from=my-files-to-copy.txt -r my/source/dir my/dest/dir
```

... or `pax` ([a standard utility](http://pubs.opengroup.org/onlinepubs/9699919799/utilities/pax.html)):

```
( cd my/source/dir && pax -w ) <my-files-to-copy.txt |
( cd my/dest/dir   && pax -r )
```

... or with `pax` if you can give an absolute path to the destination directory:

```
( cd my/source/dir && pax -rw /my/dest/dir ) <my-files-to-copy.txt
```

... or BSD `tar` (use `-T` or `--files-from=` instead of `-I` with GNU `tar`):

```
tar -c -f - -C my/source/dir -I my-files-to-copy.txt |
tar -x -f - -C my/dest/dir
```

This is all assuming that `my-files-to-copy.txt` lives in the current directory and that this directory might be different from the `my/source/dir` directory.

Comment: Why didn't you read the `cpio` man page?

Comment: @schily Why don't you say what you are referring to?

Comment: Long before you created your answer, I pointed to the cpio man page and the exact part of the man page that contains the sample code to explan how cpio is used to copy files.

Comment: @schily I saw that and I read your manual. It doesn't provide a convenient way of reading the list of files from a supplied text file though.

Comment: This is what you claim, my answer verifies that you are mistaken.

Answer (score 0):

As mentioned before in the comments, `cpio` supports what you like. Use e.g.:

```
find src/main.js src/routes/index.js src/my-app/ | cpio -pdm my/dest/dir
```

The pitfall of this method is that you need to run two processes in a way that does not speed up things since `find` needs to `stat(2)` all files and `cpio` also needs to `stat(2)` all file some time later and `cpio` only uses a single process to do the actual copy.

...or you could do it the most efficient way using my own tool, `star` (the oldest free tar implementation):

```
star -copy -p -find src/main.js src/routes/index.js src/my-app/ my/dest/dir
```

This is efficient because `star` uses `libfind` in the `star` process, only needs to call `stat(2)` once per file and forks a second process that creates the new files concurrently to the main `star` process that reads the files.

In order to avoid a slow down from this method, both `star` processes share the file content and file meta data via shared memory.

BTW: you may of course replace the list of files from my examples by something like:

```
` cat my-file-list.txt `
```

Comment: Note that using `cat my-file-list.txt` will break when any of the file names contains whitespace or other special characters.

Comment: Thisis why `star` contains a builtin `find` since 15 years...